# What exactly does "Enable Strict Checking of objc_msgSend Calls" mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is what I'm referring to:
[image]

From what I've read, an `objc_msgSend` is essentially what is happening at the c level when you send an Objective-C message, and this setting set to `Yes` ensures that the message being sent has the same number of arguments as the the receiver is expecting.

Is this correct? Also what are the advantages and disadvantages to setting this to `Yes` or `No`? Should I only set this to `Yes` in development and `No` in production?

Comment: Cocoapods has this enabled by default for each of its pods, so it seems. How can this be switched off by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are essentially correct, yes.

Apple sets it to Yes by default because it helps to find errors faster.  The only reason to set it to No would be because you are compiling legacy code that hasn't been updated to compile cleanly with this option on.

"Enable Strict Checking of objc_msgSend Calls" is a compile time check, not run time, so there is no benefit to turning it off in production.

Answer (score 7):

There's a [presentation](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/417xx2zsyyp8zcs/417/417_whats_new_in_llvm.pdf) "What's new in LLVM" on Apple's website (text of the presentation is [here](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/417)).

It looks like the compiler will now (optionally) strictly check the types of calls to *obj_msgSend*. You will have use a correctly-typed function pointer in place of directly calling *objc_msgSend*.

Example given:

```
#include <objc/message.h>
void foo(void *object) {
  typedef void (*send_type)(void *, SEL, int);
  send_type func = (send_type)objc_msgSend;
  func(object, sel_getUid("foo:"), 5);
}
```

Comment: wasn't me! I was actually wondering where that presentation was because I saw the slides and there were a little useless without someone explaining them.

Comment: yes, I get that--the text of the presentation is transcribed on the second link. You should also be able to view the original presentation via the WWDC site.